# React Nested Object State Using Memo

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-memo

I pass in props to a function component:

```js
const [accountForm, setAccountForm] = useState({})

const syncForm = (subForm, name) => {
  const form = {...accountForm, [name]: subForm}
  setAccountForm(form)
}

<>
  <ComponentA handler={syncForm} form={accountForm.objA} />
  <ComponentB handler={syncForm} form={accountForm.objB} />
  <ComponentC handler={syncForm} form={accountForm.objC} />
</>
```

The Components (A, B, & C) are written similarly like so:

```
const ComponentA = ({form, handler}) => {
  const handler = () {
    handler()
  }

  return (
    <Form onChange={handler}/>
  )
}

const areEqual = (n, p) => {
  const pForm = p.form;
  const nForm = n.form;
  const equal = pForm === nForm;
  return equal;
}

export default React.memo(ComponentA, areEqual)
```

I use a memo because Components A, B and C have the same parent, but I only want to rerender A, B or C when their subform has changed, so I don't want validations to run on other forms.

When I fill out form A, all the values are stored correctly. When I fill out a different form such as B or C, form A reverts to an empty object {}.

However, if I change the state to 3 objects instead of a nested object, it works:

```
const [objA, setObjA] = useState({});
const [objB, setObjB] = useState({});
const [objC, setObjC] = useState({});

<>
  <ComponentA form={objA} />
  <ComponentB form={objB} />
  <ComponentC form={objC} />
</>
```

Why doesn't the nested object approach work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a stale enclosure over the `accountForm` state. Looks like the `memo` HOC and `areEqual` function prevent the children components from rerendering and receiving a `handler` callback with updated state.

Use a functional state update to correctly update from any previous state instead of whatever is closed over in any callback scope.

```
const syncForm = (subForm, name) => {
  setAccountForm(form => ({
    ...form,
    [name]: subForm
  }));
}
```